# Designing REST ful ODATA APIs, How to act when result set empty? 404 or {}?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm building an ODATA compliant API using ASP.NET WebAPI?

Got a question about how it should behave when a $filter has no results?

Should it return an empty collection? or send HTTP 404 response?

Any ideas/reasoning? I'm biased towards returning an empty collection, but would it violate a recommended practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given you are not directly addressing an individual resource at a specific known Request-Uri (e.g. /resource/{uid}) **and** your collection is also a known addressable Request-Uri (e.g. /resource) then a 404 would be inappropriate.

An empty collection is what I would expect if I was consuming your API.

Comment: I agree with the answer, if not the logic used to get there :-).  The collection itself is a resource being retrieved at a specific known Request URI. The fact that it happens to be an empty collection is not something that needs to be indicated in the HTTP Status code.

Comment: What about asking for /posts/:id/comments?page=5 when I only have 4 pages.  Seems to me that that should be a 404, but I don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Stick to the [OData specifications 3.0](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/):

9.1.1. 200 OK Response Code

A GET, PUT, MERGE, or PATCH request MAY return 200 OK if the operation is completed successfully. In this case, **the response body MUST contain the value of the entity or property specified in the request URL**.

9.2.1. 404 Not Found Response Code

If the **entity or collection specified by the request URL does not exist**, the service SHOULD respond with 404 Not Found and an empty response body.

or even more precise in [OData specifications 4.0](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part1-protocol.html)

9.1.1 Response Code 200 OK

A request that does not create a resource returns 200 OK if it is completed successfully **and the value of the resource is not null**. In this case, the response body MUST contain the value of the resource specified in the request URL.

9.2.1 Response Code 404 Not Found
404 Not Found indicates **that the resource specified by the request URL does not exist**. The response body MAY provide additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think HTTP 404 should be used. The code is used to indicate a reference to a non-existing resource.

The HTTP code 204 (no content) might be a better choice then 404. But an empty collection is a better idea because it would make it easier to use the API.